# Extract number with regex

Tags: regex

I have this string:

```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Tue, 12 Nov 2013 15:26:17 GMT Server:
> Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Last-Modified: Fri, 08 Nov 2013 21:34:50 GMT
> ETag: "452//path/to/file"
> Accept-Ranges: bytes Content-Length: 26010 Connection: close
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

And would like to extract 452 which is before `//` and after `ETag`, what regex should I use?

Answer (score 3):

Let's break down your request into various syntax pieces:

> extract 452

You haven't specified whether or not the number will always be 452 or if it will be another number, but I presume it will possibly be another number since otherwise you wouldn't need a regex. First, you're looking for a digit and the syntax for that is `\d`. If you are looking for a 3-digit number, you could do `\d\d\d` which can be more cleanly written as `\d{3}`. If you want any integer, regardless of the number of digits, you would use the `+` operator, signifying one or more. So let's assume you want to catch the most general case, in which case you would use `\d+`.

> which is before //

This will require what's called a positive lookahead. You can check out [more information about lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but the gist is that it will only find matches that are followed by the text indicated by the lookahead, but not include the text of the lookahead in the match. The syntax of the lookahead is `(?=@@@)` where `@@@` is the regex that will immediately follow the match. For instance, finding `//` would be expressed by `(?=//)`.

> and after ETag

To do this, we'll use the opposite of a positive lookahead: a positive lookbehind. The syntax for that is `(?<=@@@)` where `@@@` is the regex that will immediately precede the match. For instance, finding `ETag: "` would be `(?<=ETag: ")`

Putting it all together, you would use the positive lookbehind, the match you are searching for, and the positive lookahead. So the regex you are looking for would be:

```
(?<=ETag: ")\d+(?=//)
```

This will retrieve an integer of any number of digits between the text `Etag: "` and `//`.

I presume that you already have an environment where you can run the regex. If not, other questions on Stack Exchange will be able to help you find one.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it, depending on what tool you prefer.  Using [`awk`](http://awk.info/):

```
$ awk '/ETag: "[0-9]+\/\// { printf "%s\n", gensub(".*ETag: \"([0-9]+)//.*", "\\1", $0); }' < mylog
452
```

(assuming that the file `mylog` contains your text).